# Knockout not working in razor view

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to include knockout in an MVC razor view but it does not work. I have also tried downloading an example solution which has knockout in it but it did not work. Looking at the knockout website it look it should be very simple to include knockout. I can't find many things on the net about this issue and I'm guessing it's because setting up knockout should be straightforward.

1) I installed knockout with nugget package manager in visual studio.

2) I added the script reference to include knockout in the view: `<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>` the knockout library is definitely in the scripts folder.

3) I copied and pasted the hello world example from the knockout website: `http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html` including the knockout viewmodel in the scripts section in my view.

4) ko.observable, data-bind etc are all recognised in the view by intellisense.

but the knockout does not work when I type in the textboxes eg the computed does not display the first and last name strings together.

What else do I need to do in order to setup knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the viewModel script before the closing  tag. The body's content have to be loaded before calling the **applyBindings** function.

Or you can let the script in the header and change it to listen for the document.ready event and call applyBindings when the content is loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The document had loaded before applybindings. The knockout was not updating on the page because there was a missing } in the script block.